# How to round of time to next hour and half?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have one column which contain time in `HH:mm:ss PM/AM` format. I what to round off the same time to next hour and half. for e.g if the time is `10:05:00` am then the round off time  is `11:30:00am`, if `10:55:00 am` then `11:30:00 am` (around to the next hour and half).

Comment: 10:05:00 am then the rounoff time is 11:30:00am, if 10:55:00 am then 11:30:00 am??? what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @Arvaan- Is like rounding of to next half hour , but then it would be like middle of hour, means if `4:00:00` then `4:30:00` or if `4:15:00` then next half hour is `4:45:00` and then I want it like `5:30:00`

Comment: @dwan How your logic work then? 4.00pm > 4.30pm then 10.00 > 11.30. Is adding random minute... some is 90 minute and some 30 minute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one column which contain time in HH:mm:ss PM/Am format

If I understand correctly from that sentence, I would assume you have a `DateTime` and you get it's string representation for your column with `hh:mm:ss tt` format.

If so, you can parse it to `DateTime` first, check it's minutes is `0`, if it is, add `30` minutes, if not, set zero it's `Minute` part and add `1.5` hour.

```
string s = "10:00:00 am";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    if(dt.Minute != 0)
       dt.AddMinutes(-dt.Minute).AddHours(1.5).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else
       dt.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

But of course, since you have *already* a `Datetime` instance, please do this all `AddMinutes` and/or `AddHours` process *first* then show it's *textual* representation in your columns.

Comment: Gonul- thanks for answer, but it would not add minutes in dt.

Comment: @dwan You mean the values like `10:00:00`? For this value, what should be the result exactly?

Comment: I means , I want time after add minute, means like `10:30:00`

Comment: @dwan This is _exactly_ what my code does. Please try it and see the result.

Comment: Why all this string handling? `DateTime` should always be handled as `DateTime` except for very special cases and this is not one of these.

Comment: @Gustav Probably, OP shows _textual_ representation of `DateTime` values (eg: `10:00:00 am`) in columns (what are _the_ columns by the way? DataTable columns? GridView columns? We have no idea.). That's why OP needs to parse this string representation to `DateTime` first to handle it. Then process it and show it's _textual_ representaion with a specific format. Of course you are right about _DateTime should always be handled as DateTime_. Maybe OP should do these addition process to _that_ `DateTime` instance before put it to columns but we don't have enough information about how OP does this.

Comment: @SonerGönül I see your point but can't remove the downvote now, sorry. However, people often state the format of their `DateTime` values as if it meant something - and, if needed, a parsing could be done as the first step. Thus, I much prefer the method of @Mark and @Arghya.

Comment: @Gustav Please don't worry about the downvote. It's nothing. You have a point as well. OP should do this addition/calculation for a `DateTime`instance _before_ put it's string representation to columns. Not the other way around. Other solutions are surely logical as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime src = ...;
var target = new DateTime(src.Year, src.Month, src.Day, src.Hour, 0, 0)
                .AddHours(1.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string yourstring = "10:05:00 am";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(yourstring);
if (date1.Minute > 0)
    date1 = date1.AddMinutes(-date1.Minute);
if (date1.Second > 0)
    date1 = date1.AddSeconds(-date1.Second);
date1 = date1.AddMinutes(90);
Console.WriteLine(date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now; //your original DateTime value
var result = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day,
                          dateTime.Hour + 1, 30, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Kind);
```

Hour to next hour (+1)
Minute to 30

Comment: This won't work if you add + 1 hour, and the current time is 11pm.  The runtime will take 23:00 and add 1 to it, to get 24:00, which is an unrepresentable DateTime, which will throw an exception.  Better to use @Mark Shevchenko's approach, and add the 1.5 hrs after you instantiate 'result'.